# MissingMethodException error expecting Map recieved LinkedHashMap

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following two classes

```
class Utils{
    ...

    Map clearEmptyKeys(Map source){
        ...
    }

    String mapToXml(Map source, String root = "root"){
        ...
    }
}
```

And

```
class Application {
    Utils utils = new Utils()

    ...

    String toXML(){
      return utils.mapToXml(createMap(), 'Application')
    }

    Map createMap(){
        Map response = [:]
        ...
        response = utils.clearEmptyKeys(response)
        ...
        return response
    }
}
```

As you can see in the Application class I call the Utils.mapToXML method. This use to work fine util recently. Now whenever I call this method I get

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Utils.mapToXML() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[_id:54821bd9efef088e089cc507, Active:true, ...], ...]
>   Possible solutions: mapToXml(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), mapToXml(java.util.Map)

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find a probable cause for this error so I am hoping someone has seen this issue before and can help me find my error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "recently" as in out of the blue sky or since some updates?

Comment: as in out of the blue. There was some code change but those changes only call the service that calls the Application class. Also there is a call to another method in the Utils class (part of the createMap method) that also has a Map for argument and that seems to work fine so this is way this exception is wierd.

Comment: Update: I copy/pasted the mapToXml() method to the Application class and it works fine but if I try to use the Utils.mapToXml() I still get the exception.

Comment: "...but if I try to use the Utils.mapToXml() I still get the exception." - You can't use `Utils.mapToXml(...)` because `mapToXml` is not a static method.  You have to invoke the method on a reference which points to an instance of the `Utils` class.

Comment: As Jochen said in an answer below, this is likely a case mismatch problem.  The code shows `mapToXml` but the error message includes `mapToXML`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the code you showed and the code you tried is not equal. The error suggests a typo, your text suggest the same mistake. Let's take the error message apart:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Utils.mapToXML() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[_id:54821bd9efef088e089cc507, Active:true, ...], ...] Possible solutions: mapToXml(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), mapToXml(java.util.Map)`

- "No signature of method: Utils.mapToXML()" means you tried to call mapToXML on an instance of Utils.
- "is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String)" means you tried to make the call using a LinkedHashMap and a String.
- "Possible solutions: mapToXml(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), mapToXml(java.util.Map)" means there is a mapToXml method, that fits our given objects.

So what is wrong? simple, mapToXml is what is available, and mapToXML is what you used for your call. Use less caps and you are fine.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot it was clearly in my face and I didn't see.... Definately a monday. Thanks @blackdrag

Comment: don't worry, I remember a test case written in Java one time, where I had two strings compared, and could not see why they are not equal... turned out there was a space additional in one of them. such things happen to us all

Answer (score -2):

This code compiles and runs fine in groovy, there is nothing wrong with it.

I think this is an issue with a corrupted local cache.

Try running

```
grails clean
```

and/or manually deleting the

```
yourgrailsapp/target
```

folder and recompile the source afresh with

```
grails compile
```

Comment: "I think this is an issue with a corrupted local cache." - I don't think that is likely to be the case.  The error message in the original post mentions "Utils.mapToXML()" but the code includes a method named "mapToXml".  I expect that there is a case mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Question was misleading with wrong source provided for the issue. I am correct that the code provided in the question has nothing wrong with it. Also if you compile a class then rename a method Utils.mapToXml to Utils.mapToXML in the source and the local cached compiled class did not recompile with your change, then you will see this type of error until you force a recompile which is what my answer gives clear instructions for.